# Pandas groupby - calculating distance from relative point

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Lets say I have something that looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Event':['A','A','A','A', 'A' ,'B','B','B','B','B'],  'Number':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'Ref':[False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False,True,False]})
```

What I want to do is create a new column which is the difference in Number from the True in ref.  So for the A group, the True is the last one, so the column would read -4,-3,-2,-1,0.  I have been thinking to do the following:

```
for col in df.groupby('Event'):
    temp = col[1]
    reference = temp[temp.Ref==True]
    dist1 = temp.apply(lambda x:x.Number-reference.Number,axis=1)
```

This seems to correctly calculate for each group, but I am not sure how to join the result into the df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
df["new"] = df.Number - df.Number[df.groupby('Event')['Ref'].transform('idxmax')].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  Event  Number    Ref  new
0     A       1  False   -4
1     A       2  False   -3
2     A       3  False   -2
3     A       4  False   -1
4     A       5   True    0
5     B       6  False   -3
6     B       7  False   -2
7     B       8  False   -1
8     B       9   True    0
9     B      10  False    1
```

This: `df.groupby('Event')['Ref'].transform('idxmax')` fill find the indices by group where Ref is `True`. Basically it finds the indices of the max values, so given that True = 1, and False = 0, it find the indices of the True values.

Comment: Thanks.  That is much simpler than looping like I wanted to.  What does the transform('idxmax') do?

Comment: @yankeefan11 Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In your case

```
df['new']=(df.set_index('Event').Number-df.query('Ref').set_index('Event').Number).to_numpy()
df
  Event  Number    Ref  new
0     A       1  False   -4
1     A       2  False   -3
2     A       3  False   -2
3     A       4  False   -1
4     A       5   True    0
5     B       6  False   -3
6     B       7  False   -2
7     B       8  False   -1
8     B       9   True    0
9     B      10  False    1
```

Comment: It's a creative using of  `query` :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Try `where` and grouby transform `first`

```
s = df.Number.where(df.Ref).groupby(df.Event).transform('first')
df.Number - s

Out[319]:
0   -4.0
1   -3.0
2   -2.0
3   -1.0
4    0.0
5   -3.0
6   -2.0
7   -1.0
8    0.0
9    1.0
Name: Number, dtype: float64
```