# Creating new DataFrame based on old groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58382164/pandas-groupby-calculating-distance-from-relative-point/58382263#58382263) yesterday about making a new column in a df.  Now I am curious how to make a new dataframe that contains just the extreme elements.  For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Event':['A','A','A','A', 'A' ,'B','B','B','B','B'],  'Number':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'Ref':[False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False,True,False]})
df["new"] = df.Number - df.Number[df.groupby('Event')['Ref'].transform('idxmax')].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

That gives the df in table 1.  Now I am curious as to how I could create a new df1 that is just the rows corresponding to the largest absolute value of new.  The output would be Output2 below.  I know that I can utilize something like `df1 = df.loc([df['new'].idxmin())` but that only gives rows. I am not sure how to loop through the different groups and also how to apply a numpy function as well.  I et this is a one liner, but I am not too sure how to approach

Output 1:

```
  Event  Number    Ref  new
0     A       1  False   -4
1     A       2  False   -3
2     A       3  False   -2
3     A       4  False   -1
4     A       5   True    0
5     B       6  False   -3
6     B       7  False   -2
7     B       8  False   -1
8     B       9   True    0
9     B      10  False    1
```

Output 2:

```
  Event  Number    Ref  new
0     A       1  False   -4
1     B       6  False   -3
```

Comment: `df['new'].abs().loc[df.groupby(df['Event']).idxmax()]`?

Comment: I get an error: Cannot index with multidimensional key

Comment: Scratch that, it should be `df.loc[df['new'].abs().groupby(df['Event']).idxmax()]`.

Comment: Yes that worked.  Possibly a different thread may be needed, but is there a simple way to make a new column in this that has the value of "number" with Ref = True for each group. I.e, my output 2 would have a column refnum that would have entries 5,9

Comment: `df.loc[df['Ref'], 'Number']`?

Comment: so if your first comment.  `df_new = df.loc[df['new'].abs().groupby(df['Event']).idxmax()]`.  If I wanted `df_new['refnumber'] ` to be the Number from the Number column for each group, wouldn't I need something like `df_new['refnumber'] = df.Number(df.Event==df_new.event) for temp in df.groupby()`, but that actually works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try answering your extended question here with a `merge`

```
new_df = pd.merge(df.loc[df['new'].abs().groupby(df['Event']).idxmax()],
         df.loc[df['Ref'], ['Event','Number']],
         on='Event',
         suffixes=['','_ref']
        )
```

Output:

```
  Event  Number    Ref  new  Number_ref
0     A       1  False   -4           5
1     B       6  False   -3           9
```

Comment: For the merging, the second one df.loc[df['Ref'],['Event','Number']] .  Does that not give the row where Ref is true?

Comment: @yankeefan11 I'm not following.

Comment: It does, which is what I am looking for, sorry for the confusion there.  And thanks for the help.